# AngularJS: Import text

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am not a javascript person so please apologize if this question doesn't make sense:

In my angular project/app.js I have a an array `articles` which are dictionaries of article elements (description, author, etc...)

```
var articles = [
    {   title : "Article 1",
        date : date.toDateString(),
        shortDesc : "Short description...",
        ...
    },...
]
```

This variable is then assigned to an instance variable of the controller

```
app.controller('BlogController', function () {
    this.articles = articles;
});
```

Now, instead of typing my actual short description into the article dictionary I would like import that text from another file. How do I do that?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately your question is too broad, but you can't read a file from the local filesystem (Unless the user selects a file using `<input type=file>`) - If the file is on the server, you need to make an AJAX call using the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service

Comment: hm, I dont want to clutter the code by a lot of text in between. Is there not a prettier option?

Comment: Yup, by all means save the data in a file (Or Database ), and fetch it using a request to the server, but don't confuse client side (JS) and server side, you must have an HTTP server that will serve the JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have json file and make call to it by `$http.get('data.json')`. But then again you're unable to post data to it (client side difficult to write data to file). Else you can install [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) npm module & serve your json file on it, then you can do all CRUD operation through angular's $http service. This's just for mocking purpose or faking REST API, for real project purpose you should have real web services handled by server side technologies (e.g. Java, NodeJS) or create on cloud backend-as-a-service like Firebase, AWS (dynamoDB).